# Aggregate rows with same values in specific variables, by ID and Date - Pandas

Tags: pandas

My data frame indexed and sorted by ID, date and time, and also includes X1, X2 and Y variables.
I want to aggregate rows with same values in X1 & X2 that **adjacent to each other** in every (ID, date) index.
The aggregation will be a sum of Y variable, and I want to stay with the row that "happened" earlier (by time).

Data illustration:

```
ID  date        time    X1  X2  Y
A   07/27/2019  10:00   2   3   100
                12:00   2   3   200
                14:00   2   4   50
    08/27/2019  11:00   2   4   10
                12:00   2   3   20
                13:00   2   3   30
                14:00   2   4   40
B   06/28/2019  16:00   2   4   100
                17:00   2   3   80
                18:00   2   3   80
```

Expected result:

```
ID  date        time    X1  X2  Y
A   07/27/2019  10:00   2   3   300
                14:00   2   4   50
    08/27/2019  11:00   2   4   10
                12:00   2   3   50
                14:00   2   4   40
B   06/28/2019  16:00   2   4   100
                17:00   2   3   160
```

Comment: Why is `8/27/2019` `14:00` not summed up with time `11:00` to `50` since they both have the same `X1` and `X2` value?

Comment: Because it's a different date.

Comment: It's not a different date, they are both in `08/27/2019`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is `MultiIndex` in input values:

```
print (df.index)
MultiIndex([('A', '07/27/2019', '10:00'),
            ('A', '07/27/2019', '12:00'),
            ('A', '07/27/2019', '14:00'),
            ('A', '08/27/2019', '11:00'),
            ('A', '08/27/2019', '12:00'),
            ('A', '08/27/2019', '13:00'),
            ('A', '08/27/2019', '14:00'),
            ('B', '06/28/2019', '16:00'),
            ('B', '06/28/2019', '17:00'),
            ('B', '06/28/2019', '18:00')],
           names=['ID', 'date', 'time'])
```

So first use `reset_index`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Then create unique groups by `shift` and `cumsum`, aggregate and again set `MultiIndex`:

```
g = df[['X1', 'X2']].ne(df[['X1', 'X2']].shift()).any(1).cumsum()
df = (df.groupby(['ID', 'date', 'X1', 'X2', g], sort=False)
       .agg({'time':'first', 'Y':'sum'})
       .set_index('time', append=True)
       .reset_index(level=4, drop=True)
       .reset_index(['X1','X2']))
print (df)

                     X1  X2    Y
ID date       time              
A  07/27/2019 10:00   2   3  300
              14:00   2   4   50
   08/27/2019 11:00   2   4   10
              12:00   2   3   50
              14:00   2   4   40
B  06/28/2019 16:00   2   4  100
              17:00   2   3  160
```

Comment: It works! I do have another question, if the data also includes X3 variable, and I want to take the minimum value of X3 from the rows that combined together, how should I do that? What should I add to these commands above?

Comment: @qwerty - then change `.agg({'time':'first', 'Y':'sum'})` to `.agg({'time':'first', 'Y':'sum', 'X3':'min'})`

Answer (score 1):

First we check if it's a consecutive duplicate with `diff` and if that difference is equal to `0` for both `X1` and `X2` it's a consecutive duplicate and we need to sum them.

Then we use `GroupBy` on `ID, date, X1, X2` and `sum` of `Y`:

```
s = df[['X1', 'X2']].diff(-1).eq(0).all(axis=1).cumsum()

grpd = df.groupby(['ID', 'date', 'X1', 'X2', s], sort=False).agg({'time':'first',
                                                                  'Y':'sum'}).reset_index(level=[2,3])
```

**Output**

```
                 X1  X2   time    Y
ID date                            
A  07/27/2019 1   2   3  10:00  300
              2   2   4  14:00   50
   08/27/2019 2   2   4  11:00   10
              3   2   3  12:00   50
              4   2   4  14:00   40
B  06/28/2019 4   2   4  16:00  100
              5   2   3  17:00  160
```

Comment: KeyError: 'time'

Comment: What is the output of `print(df.columns)`, `time` is one of your columns. Is it spelled with a capital T like `Time`? In your example it's with lowercase t @qwerty

Comment: X1, X2, Y. time with lowercase